# How do I lazy load images in JQuery lightSlider?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I currently have a slider ([JQuery lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/)) that has many images in and displays one at a time. This is significantly increasing my page load time. I need to apply lazy loading to the images so that only the visible images and one either side are loaded in.

I have tried the examples provided in [this Github issue](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/issues/175), however, they all seem to only deal with showing one image at a time.

Example (red background for arrow visibility):

```js
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
  item: 4,
  autoWidth: false,
  slideMargin: 1,
  mode: "slide",
  useCSS: true,
  cssEasing: 'ease',
  easing: 'linear',
  auto: true,
  loop: true,
  slideEndAnimation: true,
  pause: 4000,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  pager: false,
  enableDrag: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>

<ul id="lightSlider" style="background: red;">
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=4"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=5"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=6"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=7"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=8"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of [window.IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

I make use of `rootMargin` to extend the bounding box of the `root` element. This allows for the loading of one image to the left or right.

Once the image in the slide enters the extended bounding box, it's `data-src` attribute is used to set the `src` and load the image in. It will load all visible images and one additional image on each side (to prevent missing images being displayed).

```js
onSliderLoad: function (el) {
    var showActiveSlides = function (entries) {
        entries.forEach(function (entry) {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
                observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
        });
    };

    var imageWidth = el.find("li").outerWidth() + "px";

    var observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(showActiveSlides, {
        root: el.parent()[0],
        rootMargin: "0px "+ imageWidth + " 0px " + imageWidth
    });

    el.find("li img").each(function () {
        observer.observe(this);
    });
}
```

```js
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
  item: 4,
  autoWidth: false,
  slideMargin: 1,
  mode: "slide",
  useCSS: true,
  cssEasing: 'ease',
  easing: 'linear',
  auto: true,
  loop: true,
  slideEndAnimation: true,
  pause: 4000,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  pager: false,
  enableDrag: false,
  onSliderLoad: function(el) {
    var showActiveSlides = function(entries) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
          observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    };

    var imageWidth = el.find("li").outerWidth() + "px";

    var observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(showActiveSlides, {
      root: el.parent()[0],
      rootMargin: "0px " + imageWidth + " 0px " + imageWidth
    });

    el.find("li img").each(function() {
      observer.observe(this);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>

<ul id="lightSlider" style="background: red;">
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=1"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=2"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=3"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=4"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=5"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=6"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=7"></li>
  <li><img data-src="https://picsum.photos/100?random=8"></li>
</ul>
```